I want to read 32 bit floating point variable from Modbus RS485 slave using Arduino as Master
I have a energy meter, which has a modbus port. The registry information is available on the instruction manual. I am able to read the data using arduino, but the format is wrong.
Using open modscan software, I have attached the screenshots. When the data type is selected as u16 then the data doesn't make any sense. When I switched the data type to .32 then I can clearly get the data is mains voltage 240 V in register 40141 and 143. There is no CT connected as of now, so no current data. The value at register 157 is frequency.
WHen reading from arduino ModbusMaster library then I am getting these values.
[17:58:28:217] 62322.00␍␊  // 40141
[17:58:28:217] 17260.00␍␊
[17:58:28:217] 62322.00␍␊   // 40143
[17:58:28:250] 17260.00␍␊
[17:58:28:250] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:250] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:250] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:250] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:284] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:284] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:284] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:284] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:284] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:317] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:317] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:317] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:317] 42972.00␍␊   // 157
[17:58:28:317] 16967.00␍␊
[17:58:28:338] 0.00␍␊
[17:58:28:338] 0.00␍␊

I tried changing the variable and return type of the modbus function the the library to float but nothing worked.
I am assuming this is IEEE754 32 bit floating point variable for the data for the voltage and frequency (and every other data).
_u16ResponseBuffer[i] = word(u8ModbusADU[2 * i + 3], u8ModbusADU[2 * i + 4]);

from this statement it looks like the library is reading 8 bit values and converting to 16 bit and so not able to read 32 bit information. I have previously make an arduino slave which stores a value in IEEE754 format and a master was able to read that info. So should not be an arduino issue because it is an 8 bit MCU.
What could be a possible solution?

I'd need to study this a while in order to understand what you're asking. But it sounds very similar to something I'd answered previously. Have you read through this?

The using the function that I showed in that answer with your frequency values: modbus_16bit_register_pair_to_float(16967, 42972)) gives 49.914, which is a plausible line frequency. If that in fact answers your question it may make sense to mark this as a duplicate question.  modbus_16bit_register_pair_to_float(17260, 62322)) gives 236.951, plausible voltage value.

Also see this and this and this.

I think this should work. The first link you shared. Thanks a lot. Let me do some more testing and I will share my results soon.

This solution is working fine. Thanks a lot! @timemage
